# does anyone have used toPromise and Promise.all from rxjs in http

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Has anyone used `toPromise` and `Promise.all` from rxjs in http? Please give me an example.
How can I check both of the request is success in component with `promise.all` return some message like API is success?

```js
getPostAsync() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                    .pipe(map((res:Response) => { return res.json();}))
                    .pipe(catchError((error) => { return throwError(error);}))
}
```

```js
getPostAsync1() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                    .pipe(map((res:Response) => { return res.json();}))
                    .pipe(catchError((error) => { return throwError(error);}))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `toPromise` nor `Promise.all` when handling requests. It's better to handle it using observables and operators. I've written an [article about replacing Promises with RxJS](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/10/journey-promises-to-rxjs/). Instead of `Promise.all`, I'd use `forkJoin` to listen for the completion of two or more requests.

Comment: Thank you . ohhh it is easy to do with forkJoin.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you mark one of the answers as accepted so people know this question has been answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinelatest for multiple requests
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

```
combineLatest(this.http.get('/api'), this.http.get('/api2'))
.subscribe((res: any) => {
    const res = res[0];
    const res2 = res[1];
});
```

Comment: This is same as forkJoin btw i will go with forkjoin thank you for your response